# Statistical test for cluster independence?

Tags: clustering, manova

1) If I want to test whether the cluster in red at the bottom figure [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/aflyax/virus_scikit/blob/master/virus_clustering.ipynb) is a statistically separate cluster from nearby ones, what do I use? MANOVA? Anything else?

2) Any suggestions how to implement your answer to 1) in Python (as in: is there an existing package in scikit-learn, scipy, numpy, statsmodels, whatever), R, or Julia?

Thanks...